# how to equally divide the layout in 2 parts in android

Tags: android, view

I want two divider a layout equally in two parts in phone as well as tablet. Below things I have tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LayoutActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use **weights** in your TextViews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should have to use weightSum in Layout and set weight in both textview see the example :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LayoutActivity" 
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: `android:weightSum ` is **optional**.

Comment: you havnt given orientation in linearlayout

Comment: bydefault LinearLayout orientation is horizontal so its up to developer whether they want this horizontally or vertically if they want vertically then they need to set orientation

Comment: so u must explain it to new user

Answer (score 2):

You should add a weight container to it and an orientation which depends if you want it vertically or horizontally.

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".LayoutActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight= 0.5/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight= 0.5 />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use weight attribute for linear layout to make it what you want to do. Like you want equally divide the textview then give

> android:layout_weight="1"

in both textview

Answer (score 0):

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LayoutActivity" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```